# Error with react-native-purchases in React Native: "There was a problem with the store."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, revenuecat

I'm currently working on a React Native app (Expo) (version 0.72.4) and I'm using the "react-native-purchases" package (version ^6.6.4) to integrate with RevenueCat.

When I execute the following code:

```
try {
    Purchases.setLogLevel(Purchases.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG);

    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    } else if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Purchases.configure({ apiKey: "goog_api-key" });
    }

    try {
      const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      console.log(offerings);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I get the following error message:

LOG [Error: There was a problem with the store.]

I've ensured that the API key is correctly placed for Android. Is anyone familiar with this issue or knows what could be causing it? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

I attempted to get the offerings using the Purchases.getOfferings() method.

Answer (score 0):

You must login to Google Play store on the phone.